# Not able to store values to a nested table in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a function to show values for monthly data according to the selection made by the user in monthly report. Code snippet below is just trying to fetch values in a nested table and once data is loaded successfully in a nested table, I will call the function to display the table. I have tried a few things; but am running into issues while loading data. Below are 2 different SQLs to create this function but both of them are getting same error regarding incorrect values; I have tried a few things but to no avail:

Snippet 1:

```
/* Formatted on 10/16/2012 8:40:45 AM (QP5 v5.215.12089.38647) */

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tempObject AS OBJECT
(
   kpiid number,
   kpigroup VARCHAR2 (300)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tempTable AS TABLE OF tempObject;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KPI_HORIZON.Monthly_All_Data (
   mainarea IN VARCHAR2)

   RETURN tempTable
IS
   MonthlyData   temptable := temptable ();
   n             INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN

   IF (mainarea = 'ALL')

   THEN
      FOR r IN (SELECT DISTINCT kpiid, kpigroup
                  FROM kpi_summary_reporting
                 WHERE kpifrequency = 'Monthly' AND active_ind = 'Y')
      LOOP
         monthlydata.EXTEND;
         n := n + 1;
         monthlydata (n) := tempobject (r.kpiid, r.kpigroup);
      END LOOP;
  END IF;

   RETURN MonthlyData;
END;
```

Error: [Error] PLS-00306 (26: 29): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEMPOBJECT'

Snippet2:

```
/* Formatted on 10/16/2012 8:27:22 AM (QP5 v5.215.12089.38647) */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tempObject AS OBJECT
(
   kpiid NUMBER,
   kpigroup VARCHAR2 (300)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tempTable AS TABLE OF tempObject;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KPI_HORIZON.Monthly_All_Data (
   mainarea IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN tempTable
AS
   MonthlyData   temptable := temptable ();
BEGIN
   IF (mainarea = 'ALL')
   THEN
      SELECT DISTINCT ksr.kpiid, ksr.kpigroup
        INTO MonthlyData 
        FROM kpi_summary_reporting ksr
       WHERE kpifrequency = 'Monthly' AND active_ind = 'Y';
   ELSE
      SELECT DISTINCT kpiid, kpigroup
        INTO MonthlyData
        FROM kpi_summary_reporting;
   END IF;

   RETURN MonthlyData;
END;
```

Error: [Error] ORA-00947 (24: 9): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this assuming that the data is small enough that it really makes sense to load it entirely into a nested table in the server's PGA.  If the data volume is larger, you probably want to use a pipelined table function instead.

Since your nested table is a table of object types, you need to use the object type constructor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KPI_HORIZON.Monthly_All_Data (
   mainarea IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN tempTable
IS
   MonthlyData   temptable;
BEGIN
   IF (mainarea = 'ALL')
   THEN
      SELECT tempObject( kpiid, kpigroup )
        BULK COLLECT INTO monthlydata
        FROM kpi_summary_reporting
       WHERE kpifrequency = 'Monthly' 
         AND active_ind = 'Y';
   END IF;

   RETURN MonthlyData;
END;
```

I'm always dubious when I see a `DISTINCT` in a query.  Do you really expect to get duplicate rows that you need to remove?  If not, you'll be much better served removing the `DISTINCT` as I did above.  If you really need the `DISTINCT`, then your object type would need a `MAP` or an `ORDER` method which would complicate the example a bit.

A demonstration of this working

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tempObject AS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     kpiid NUMBER,
  4     kpigroup VARCHAR2 (300)
  5  );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tempTable AS TABLE OF tempObject;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table kpi_summary_reporting (
  2  kpiid integer,
  3  kpigroup varchar2(300),
  4  kpifrequency varchar2(30),
  5  active_ind varchar2(1)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into kpi_summary_reporting values( 1, 'Foo', 'Monthly', 'Y' );

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Monthly_All_Data (
  2     mainarea IN VARCHAR2)
  3     RETURN tempTable
  4  IS
  5     MonthlyData   temptable;
  6  BEGIN
  7     IF (mainarea = 'ALL')
  8     THEN
  9        SELECT tempObject( kpiid, kpigroup )
 10          BULK COLLECT INTO monthlydata
 11          FROM kpi_summary_reporting
 12         WHERE kpifrequency = 'Monthly'
 13           AND active_ind = 'Y';
 14     END IF;
 15     RETURN MonthlyData;
 16* END;
 17  /

Function created.

SQL> select monthly_all_data( 'ALL' ) from dual;

MONTHLY_ALL_DATA('ALL')(KPIID, KPIGROUP)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEMPTABLE(TEMPOBJECT(1, 'Foo'))
```

Comment: if i try to run this query i get the following error: [Error] ORA-02315 (10: 14): PL/SQL: ORA-02315: incorrect number of arguments for default constructor

Comment: @user1750578 - Is `tempObject` defined in your system exactly the same way it is defined in your question?  If I create a dummy `kpi_summary_reporting` table in my schema and remove the `KPI_HORIZON` schema qualifier, the code works in my environment.